# KendoUI dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am having a difficult time selecting an option from a KendoUI dropdown and then clicking the search button to get the results. The issue is the KendoUI dropdown which is different than regular dropdown that you could use SendKeys.

[**UI Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy3bG.jpg)

Code

```
public static void SelectSearchOption()
{
    Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".k-dropdown > span:nth-child(1)")).Click();
    Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".k-animation-container")).Click();
    Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Search")).Click();
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: #e6e6e6; padding: 10px 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="k-input form-control" id="searchColonies" placeholder="Colony Name" data-bind="value: searchParameter" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="width: 100%;" title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="549cac5d-6e77-4c5b-b528-cc6321984d37">
                <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-input">- All Statuses -</span>
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span>
                </span>
                <input data-role="dropdownlist" data-value-primitive="true" data-text-field="Status" data-value-field="StatusID" data-option-label="- All Statuses -" data-bind="value: selectedStatus, source: statuses" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="width: 100%;" class="k-widget k-combobox k-header k-combobox-clearable">
                <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
                    <input class="k-input" autocomplete="off" style="" title="" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="- All Organizations -" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="5e10bcaf-d176-4665-821b-8e94d8ce1be8" type="text">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span>
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select" role="button" tabindex="-1"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span>
                </span>
                <input data-role="combobox" data-value-primitive="true" data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="OrganizationID" data-placeholder="- All Organizations -" data-bind="value: selectedOrganization, source: organizations, events: { change: onOrganizationChange }" style="width: 100%; display: none;" aria-disabled="false">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="width: 100%;" class="k-widget k-combobox k-header k-combobox-clearable">
                <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-disabled">
                    <input class="k-input" autocomplete="off" style="" title="" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="- All Projects -" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="" aria-busy="false" disabled="disabled" type="text">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close k-hidden" title="clear" role="button" tabindex="-1"></span>
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input data-role="combobox" data-value-primitive="true" data-text-field="ProjectNumber" data-value-field="ProjectNumber" data-placeholder="- All Projects -" data-bind="value: selectedProject, source: projects, enabled: selectedOrganization" style="width: 100%; display: none;" aria-disabled="true" disabled="disabled">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <a class="k-button k-button-primary" data-bind="click: searchColonies">Search</a>
                <a class="k-button" data-bind="click: resetColoniesGrid">Reset</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: U can directly chose items in dropdown list byDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".k-dropdown > span:nth-child(1)")).send_keys("enter words in dropdownlist here")

Comment: could you add complete html here?

Comment: Sendkeys not working   I have a textbox, KendoUi dropdown and 2 other dropdowns that sendkeys working for them but not for KendoUI dropdown  ,  I update the HTML

Comment: I edited original posting with the complete HTML Also added image

Comment: Hi JeffC can you help me finishing my Automation thank you

Comment: So what's the error you are getting? You say it doesn't work but you didn't provide any details. You need to treat this like any other HTML since it isn't a `SELECT` element. You will need to click the dropdown to open it and then click the desired option from the dropdown. You will likely have to click the option using an XPath with the text of the desired option in the locator. You provided HTML but it doesn't contain any data. Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: I am not getting error but Xpath only select one of the options therefore the search results are incorrect.

Comment: the HTML ,CSS or Xpath is no working "- All Statuses-   is the dropdown that has 3 options  for  Active, inactive, hidden,FOR  example   When chose Hidden option  outerHTML  all of the options have exactly the same xpath and CCS -->  <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Hidden</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span> other dropdowns no problems, only this one is different, see image in original posting 2 dropdown